# Bitbucket pipeline caching dependencies across repository

Tags: java, gradle, bitbucket

Let's say I have 2 repository in my bitbucket account in the same project

1. common-api
2. common-web

Now, common-core has a dependency of common-api at compile time.

In this scenario, In local, I can publish common-api to maven local so it available to common-core.

But with bucket pipeline with Gradle its says common-api not found.

Any solution or workaround for this without using public artifactory/repository?

My bitbucket.pipelines.yml

```
image: openjdk:8

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - gradle
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          # You must commit the Gradle wrapper to your repository
          # https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html
          - bash ./gradlew build -i -x javadoc
```